# Read remote script env variable

Tags: shell-script, ssh, environment-variables

I'm executing a script on a server with remote ssh

```
#!/bin/bash
VPS_IP=192.168.1.10
VPS_USERNAME=root
VPS_PASSWORD=ubuntu
sshpass -p "$VPS_PASSWORD" ssh $VPS_USERNAME@$VPS_IP 'bash -s' < /arguments1.sh
echo $LC_ip
```

in the arguments1.sh file is

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_ip=$(http://v6.ident.me)
```

How do I get the LC_ip back in the local script?

Comment: Something's wrong with arguments1.sh, I'm pretty sure that code will never do anything helpful and instead sets $LC_ip to an empty string. What do you want arguments1.sh to do?

Answer (score 0):

Putting `echo $LC_ip` in your script would only print the value of $LC_ip on the local machine's environment.

I believe the easiest way to fetch the value from the remote machine is to print it to stdout on the remote machine.

To do that I think you might be able to modify your arguments1.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LC_ip=$(http://v6.ident.me)
echo $LC_ip
```

But that probably won't do anything either since `$(http://v6.ident.me)` isn't a valid command (at least on any system I'm familiar with).

Try the following in your arguments script and see what you get:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LC_ip=$(http://v6.ident.me)
echo "The value of LC_ip is $LC_ip"
```

Comment: thanks rexypoo, it must be curl http.... yes your right.

only i need multiple variables back and with the echo i can do only 1 right?

Comment: It depends a little bit on the form of the variables you want to pass back: if they can contain spaces and newline characters it's a bit harder. Does echo work in the single-variable case? I don't use sshpass so I'm not entirely certain, but if it does work I can expand the answer a little for multiple variables.

Comment: no there are no spaced in there, i never use always use_ linux is very shitty with spaces